# How to check if a text file contains URL or JSON?

Tags: python, flask

I have written codes (FLASK app) that gets a text file and it checks if it contains URL or JSON. If is a URL, gets it and shows as a JSON to the user else if it is a JSON, it only shows it as as it is to the user. I would like to know if my codes are a correct representation of these things.The text file could be either in the following forms (JSON or URL):

> text.txt >
> '{"name":"John", "age":30, "car":null}'
>
> text.txt > http://example.com/contents/example.json

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, abort, make_response
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
import requests, json
import urllib.request as request

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


@app.route('path', methods=["POST"])
@app.error
class test(Resource):     
    def do_test(self):
        
        with open("test.txt", "r") as md:
            text = md.read()
            for i in text.readlines():
                URL = requests.get(i)
                if URL.ok:
                    data = json.loads(URL.read())
                    return jsonify(data)
                else:
                    abort(make_response(jsonify(404, message = "No URL found"),400))
            elif text.read(1) in '{[':
                data = json.load(text)
                return jsonify(data)    
                  
            
api.add_resource(test, 'path')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: What's `file`? What's `make_response`? What's `jsonify`? What's the contents of the file in the one or the other case?

Comment: I just edited the codes. the file must be replaced with text. I also imported the make_response

Comment: ... What's the contents of the file in the one or the other case?

Comment: Actually, the content of the file is unknown for now as it will be provided later to me. I just want to create a logic that checks if the text file is URL or JSON. If it is a JSON it directly shows to the user if not and it is a URL, gets it and extract its data and show it as a json to the user.

Comment: I know what you are trying to do. Can you provide two example files for both possible outcomes?

Comment: One example could be a text file contains a url for example https://helloworld.com. And we assume that this address contains some data.So, the program reads this text file and identify if contain a url. After identifying that the text file has this url, it downloads it and then return its contents as a JSON to the user. As another example, there is a text file contains only JSON but the program needs to identify if the contain is JSON or not. If it is JSON then return it to the user with content. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: \*sigh\*... Don't describe the files to me. Just put two sample files into your question.

Comment: Does your text file *really* contain single quotes? In that case it's not JSON. What's so hard with openening a text editor on each file type, hitting CTRL+C, and then making a code block here, and hitting CTRL+V, to show the files **as they are**? I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a try/except block. Something like

```
try:
   data = json.load(text)
except JSONDecodeError:
   url = text
```

You will need to test it and add the proper exceptions, JSONDecodeError is just an example, but you get the point.